# How i can see generated requests for endpoints in IntelliJ

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, frontend, backend

I'm trying to make a full stack application, so it includes a lot of endpoints...
I don't see the green button on the side for generated requests that displays file with type of endpoint and url of it, so I'm interested how to make it visible?

Btw I am using Spring boot Maven and React for my project.

I tried in Settings and more, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.